# C# detect pressing Windows key

Tags: c#, keydown, hotkeys, windows-key

I create a text box for entering a combination of global hot keys, which can then be used in the program. For this purpose I use event `TextBox.KeyDown` and look the `KeyEventArgs`. But the problem is that I have not found how to use the `KeyEventArgs` to see whether the Windows-key is pressed. Properties `KeyCode`, `Modifiers` use enum type `Keys`, which has no value for the Windows-key, because when you press the Windows-key, then `KeyDown` event is triggered, but the `Modifiers` property contains `None`.

What to do?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try with `Keys.LWin`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Keys.LWin` and `Keys.RWin` for the keycode enum